# Reading back ListBox values and setting default

Tags: c#, windows

I'm new to this site, and basically I have created a Windows Form using C#.

On this form I have 3 values.

I have a button to access the values in my ListBox.

How could I make it so when the form loads, the first element in my list box is highlighted?

I was also wondering is there a way to start the indexing off for 1, if the first element in my list is selected? rather than 0?

I hope I have stated this as clearly as I should,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the first index, add this line to the `OnLoad` event of the form:

```
myListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

As for your second question about changing the indexing range, the answer is no. You could use 1 to whatever, but then you would have to use -1 after. Like so:

```
myListbox.Items.Remove(Your_Value - 1);
```